# Noninteractive confirmation of eager options in the Python click library

Tags: python, user-interface, testing, command-line-interface, python-click

I had a click subcommand for resetting a config file, `myprog config-reset`:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.confirmation_option(prompt="Are you sure?")
def config_reset():
    """Reset the user configuration."""
    click.echo("Success")
```

The use of [`click.confirmation_option`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/?highlight=confirmation_option#click.confirmation_option) allowed me to pass `--yes` to bypass the "Are you sure?" prompt, which was useful for testing:

```
$ myprog config-reset --yes  # No interactive confirmation required.
```

For other reasons, I've now merged the `config-reset` subcommand into a general `config` subcommand, such that the user can call `myprog config --reset`. I achieved this by using an eager option that executes the function `config_reset` if `--reset` is present, instead of executing the main function body:

```
def config_reset(ctx, option, value):
    if not value or ctx.resilient_parsing:  # Copied from click docs.
        return

    click.confirm("Are you sure?", abort=True)
    # If we got this far, the config should be reset...

@click.command()
@click.option(
    "--reset",
    is_flag=True,
    callback=config_reset,
    expose_value=False,
    is_eager=True,
    help="Reset the user configuration to the default.",
)
def config():
    """Show the configuration."""
    # print config here...
```

The problem now, is that I don't have a way to pass a `--yes` option to bypass the interactive "Are you sure?" confirmation. Is there a way to implement a `click.confirmation_option` in combination with `is_eager=True`? Essentially I want to be able to write...

```
$ myprog config --reset --yes
```

...and have the config reset itself without confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `--yes` option to skip the confirmation in the eager callback by creating a custom `click.Option` class.

#### Custom Class

```py
def confirm_eager_option(*args, confirm_skip_flag_name='yes'):

    class ConfirmEagerOption(click.Option):
        def __init__(self, param_decls, **kwargs):
            assert not param_decls, 'pass options names into confirm_eager_option()'
            self.original_callback = kwargs['callback']
            kwargs['callback'] = self.callback_handler
            kwargs['is_eager'] = True
            kwargs['is_flag'] = True
            kwargs['expose_value'] = False
            super().__init__(args, **kwargs)

        def handle_parse_result(self, ctx, opts, args):
            # grab the parsed options for later reference
            self.parse_opts = opts
            return super().handle_parse_result(ctx, opts, args)

        def callback_handler(self, ctx, option, value):
            if value and not self.parse_opts.get('help'):
                # If we have the confirm flag, then set value to None
                if self.parse_opts.get(confirm_skip_flag_name):
                    value = None
                self.original_callback(ctx, option, value)

        # build a decorator with our skip flag
        confirm_skip_option = click.option(
            f'--{confirm_skip_flag_name}', is_flag=True, expose_value=False, is_eager=True,
            help=f"Skip confirmation for {args[0]}"
        )

    return ConfirmEagerOption
```

#### Using the Custom Class:

To use the custom class, first build the class by calling `confirm_eager_option()` and pass
it the option names, and the skip flag name like:

```py
confirm_eager_option_cls = confirm_eager_option(
    '--reset', confirm_skip_flag_name='yes')
```

Then pass the class as the `cls` argument of the `click.option` decorator, and add another
decorator for the skip option like::

```py
@click.command()
@click.option(cls=confirm_eager_option_cls, callback=config_reset,
              help="Reset the user configuration to the default.")
@confirm_eager_option_cls.confirm_skip_option
def cli():
    ...
```

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.option()` decorator
usually instantiates a `click.Option` object but allows this behavior to be over ridden with the `cls`
parameter. So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Option` in our own class and over
ride the desired methods.

In this case we override the `handle_parse_result()` method. The overridden method allows us to
capture the other parsed options, and then look at those options in the eager callback hook to decide if
skipping the confirmation is allowed.

#### Test Code:

```py
confirm_eager_option_cls = confirm_eager_option(
    '--reset', confirm_skip_flag_name='yes')

def config_reset(ctx, option, value):
    if value is None or value:
        if value:
            click.echo('Confirming reset...')
            # click.confirm("Are you sure?", abort=True)
        click.echo('Resetting...')

@click.command()
@click.option(cls=confirm_eager_option_cls, callback=config_reset,
              help="Reset the user configuration to the default.")
@confirm_eager_option_cls.confirm_skip_option
def cli():
    click.echo('running command')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        '',
        '--reset',
        '--reset --yes',
        '--help',
    )

    import sys, time
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cli(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Test Results:

```
Click Version: 7.1.2
Python Version: 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> 
running command
-----------
> --reset
Confirming reset...
Resetting...
running command
-----------
> --reset --yes
Resetting...
running command
-----------
> --help
Usage: test_code.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --reset  Reset the user configuration to the default.
  --yes    Skip confirmation for --reset
  --help   Show this message and exit.
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! It's a shame this isn't a feature of vanilla Click.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create custom option.
See the [documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/advanced/?highlight=eager#callback-evaluation-order):

> All eager parameters are evaluated before all non-eager parameters,
> but again in the order as they were provided on the command line by
> the user.

So what you need to do is, to add --yes param, which is eager too and to provide it before the reset param.
Here is an example command:

```
@cli.command()
@click.option('--yes', is_flag=True, is_eager=True)
@click.option(
    "--reset",
    is_flag=True,
    callback=config_reset,
    is_eager=True,
)
def my_command(reset, yes):
    pass
```

if you call the command that way:

```
$ my_command --yes --reset
```

You will have access to the --yes option in the callback:

```
def config_reset(ctx, option, value):
    print(ctx.params) # prints {'yes': True}
```

So, what you need to do is:

```
def config_reset(ctx, option, value):
    if not ctx.params.get('yes'):
        click.confirm("Are you sure?", abort=True)
```

And remember, that the order of your arguments does metter:

```
$ my_command --reset --yes
```

won't work for you.